# border around drop down list

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Can i somehow remove this dashed border in drop down list. Every time i click on drop down list i get this dashed border. Example is in image.

[image]

edit:

css:

```
option {
    height: 20px;
    padding: 7px 0 5px 3px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}
```

html:

```
<select onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')">
                <option value="">Razvrsti restavracije po</option>
                <option value="#">Odrto test</option>
                <option value="#">Odrto test</option>
                <option value="#">Odrto test</option>
                <option value="#">Odrto test</option>
                <option value="#">Odrto test</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: Is this in a browser? Which one?

Comment: It indicates which control currently has the input focus. Not everyone uses the mouse for everything. That big board of keys in front of you can navigate around the screen, too. **Please leave this alone**, no matter how "ugly" you think it looks.

Answer (score 4):

I think the border is used by some people who prefer to navigate using their keyboard. So it might not be a good idea to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible with CSS. What is known is that dashed border has the same color as text, so if you set the text-color same as your background it will "disappear" **but** your text will too:

Maybe you can play with some javascript:

```
onmouseover="this.style.color='#DFF1FA'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#000000'"
```

Or add this at your onchange att: `this.blur()`

```
<select onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top'); this.blur()">
                <option value="" style="color:black">Razvrsti restavracije po</option>
                <option value="#">Odrto test</option>
                <option value="#">Odrto test</option>
                <option value="#">Odrto test</option>
                <option value="#">Odrto test</option>
                <option value="#">Odrto test</option>
            </select>
```

With it the dashed outline will disappear after choosing an option.

You can do even more...

JavaScript rulez!

Answer (score 0):

You can disable such borders using the css outline property:

```
outline: none;
```

Comment: i already have outline: none; but not working. i am using firefox browser.

Comment: Try to put it on select instead of option, or maybe both.